Questions about tax deductions with help of derivative products
S.Neftci in his book "Principles of Financial Engineering" pays some attention to practical usage of derivative contracts to get tax deductions. As one of the examples, author mentioned that it's possible to simulate Wash sale - Wikipedia with a synthetic short stock position. I'm very interested to learn more on this topic. 
Are questions about the usage of derivatives to get tax deductions and the way regulators try to control this usage in scope of the discussion on Quant.StackExchange?

It could be in scope if the question is about the quantitative techniques and tools. Anything about legal issues is really borderline (and also difficult to answer because of jurisdiction).
